# ssl certificate causes one file not working

Tags: php, mysql, http, ssl, https

Recently I got the SSl Certificate and got installed , every thing later seems to be working fine but one file(index1.php) doesn,t work correctly and the file works only on http not on https 
the tab Signup(#Signup) is not showing up only(#sigin) is working (in the case of using .) but working perfectly when using (http://.. )and I could not see any mistake.here is my php file:

```
<?php /* Main page with two forms: sign up and log in */
require 'db.php';
session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>  <title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
<?php include 'css/css.html'; ?></head>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if (isset($_POST['login'])) { //user logging in

    require 'login.php';

}

elseif (isset($_POST['register'])) { //user registering

    require 'register.php'; }}?>
<body>  <div class="form">

  <ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

     <div id="login">   
      <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

      <form action="index1.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" required autocomplete="off" name="email"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" required autocomplete="off" name="password"/>
      </div>

      <p class="forgot"><a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password?</a></p>

      <button class="button button-block" name="login" />Log In</button>

      </form>

    </div>

    <div id="signup">   
      <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

      <form action="index1.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            First Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name='firstname' />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name='lastname' />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            City <span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name='City' />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Postal<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name='Postal' />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Street<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name='Street' />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            buildingNo<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text"required autocomplete="off" name='buildingNo' />
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            phone<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name='phone' />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Room (if any)
          </label>
          <input type="text"notrequired autocomplete="off" name='noteadress' />
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email"required autocomplete="off" name='email' />
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" name='password'/>

      </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
       <h3 style="color:green"> By clicking Register, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our <span><a  href="../../../../forms/terms-and-conditions/index.html">Data Use Policy</a></span>, including our Cookie Use</h3>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="register" />Register</button>

      </form>

    </div>  

  </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `<script src='http://cdnjs...` - If you're under `https`, all assets (js, css, images etc) needs to be called under https as well or some browsers might block those files for being "unsafe"

Comment: Change `"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com..."` to `"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com..."` will work in both cases.

Comment: As @Syscall and Magnus Eriksson suggested your problem probably is due to mixed content. When pages are server from https but the static files (jquery javascript file) from http, they aren't loaded and your in page anchors doesn't work due to lack of jquery. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content) is a good article to read about mixed contents.

Answer (score -1):

Might try changing:

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

To:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

If simply changing the http to https doesn't work, you will need to find the https version of the link.

Comment: The problem solved, by changing the script from http to https

Comment: now the form above is entering the registration information to Mysql. If I want to choose the city and the street from a drop down list using options and ejecting that option to my table in Mysql how I can do this?

Comment: I don't quite follow the question.  It may be better to mark this question as answered and open another question specific to your problem.